# How can I efficiently disaggregate data in a Dataframe (given a set of weights, mapping, etc.)?

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe that holds data at a particular level of aggregation - let's call it regional.

I also have a dict that explains how these regions are formed. Something like this:

```
map = {'Alabama': 'region_1', 'Arizona': 'region_1', 'Arkansas': 'region_2' ... }
```

And a set of weights for each state within its region, stored as a series:

```
Alabama    .25
Arizona    .75
Arkansas   .33
....
```

Is there an efficient way to apply this disaggregation map to get a new dataframe at a State level?

Aggregation is easy:

```
df_regional = df_states.groupby(map).sum()
```

But how can I do disaggregation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming two dataframes, `df_states` and `df_regional`, with the following 
structure:

```
In [36]: df_states
Out[36]: 
          Weight    Region
Alabama     0.25  region_1
Arizona     0.75  region_1
Arkansas    0.33  region_2

In [37]: df_regional
Out[37]: 
          Value
region_1    100
region_2     80
```

Does `pandas.merge` arrange the data in a way that seems useful?

```
In [39]: df = pandas.merge(df_states, df_regional, left_on='Region', right_index=True)

In [40]: df
Out[40]: 
          Weight    Region  Value
Alabama     0.25  region_1    100
Arizona     0.75  region_1    100
Arkansas    0.33  region_2     80

In [41]: df.Weight * df.Value
Out[41]: 
Alabama     25.0
Arizona     75.0
Arkansas    26.4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [238]: map = {'Alabama': 'region_1', 'Arizona': 'region_1', 'Arkansas': 'region_2'}

In [239]: weigths = pandas.Series([.25, .75, .33], index=['Alabama', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas'])

In [240]: df_states = pandas.DataFrame({'map': pandas.Series(map), 'weigths': weigths})

In [241]: df_states
Out[241]:
               map  weigths
Alabama   region_1     0.25
Arizona   region_1     0.75
Arkansas  region_2     0.33

In [242]: df_regional = df_states.groupby('map').sum()

In [243]: df_regional
Out[243]:
          weigths
map
region_1     1.00
region_2     0.33
```